# Database mirroring between Windows Azure VMs

Tags: sql-server, azure, load-balancing, database-mirroring

I have two windows server 2012 data-center R2 VMs with SQL Server standard 2012 running. I installed my both application and the db server on each of VMs. Both VMs reside within the same cloud service.

Also I setup load balancing between two VMs through port:80. Now it's a matter of mirroring the databases. I tried to setup SQL Mirroring but no luck so far. I'm not sure how these two VMs communicate with each other via the same port 5022.

Also I've done some reading but still I'm not sure what is the possible way of doing this. I definitely need a help now.

Questions:
a) Do I need to set up a virtual network in order to mirror databases?
b) Can I mirror databases resides within the same virtual network?
c) If my assumptions above are incorrect, what is the best way forward on this?

Thanks in advance!!

**UPDATE:** I managed to setup Principle server in VM1 and both Mirror & Witness servers in VM2 (If you have resources best way to have them in separated VMs). Both VMs reside within same Virtual Network and same cloud service.

So when the Principle is not available, Witness automatically set the Mirror to Principle and it's no longer in the recovery state.

If you're planning to have both Witness & Mirror SQL instances within the same server, Make sure you use a different Port for Witness server. 
eg.

```
- Principle : 5022
- Mirror    : 5022
- Witness   : 5023
```

Comment: Are the VM's in the same affinity group?

Comment: Yes, I put both of them in the same region which East Asia.

Comment: What does this question have to do with mirroring? This is purely a networking issue in Azure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They can be in same Cloud Service and placing them into the same CS will make life simpler, because of no need to deal with public endpoints. In fact Cloud Service is just a container for VMs and/or Roles that's also associated with an implicitly created network (thus you need an endpoint to access it from outside).

It is also recommended to put VMs into the same Availability Set, in this case Azure will try to do not shutdown all the VMs at the same time.

The simplest way to setup DBM is to use certificates. You can see example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191140.aspx).

Note: don't forget to setup witness if you need an automatic failover.

Comment: Hi Evgeny, I want to mirror the DBs to get use of the load balancing. i.e. If I can maintain a DB copy of VM1 and store it on VM2. If the VM1 is not available, My application will be online with VM2 with the help of Azure load balancing. But not sure what is the best way to setup my VMs without loosing both features. i.e. DB mirroring and load balancing.

Comment: Also does it mean that I don't necessarily need to have virtual network? can it be archived same with same cloud service?

Comment: Unfortunately, DBM is only useable for load balancing if you are ok with using DB snapshots with it, which means your data on the "secondaries" will be always behind.
Other options are AlwaysOn Availability Groups (especially in SQL 2014, where you have up to 8 readable secondary replicas).
If you don't need a high availability, but only load balancing you might take a look on the log shipping. It will give you virtually unlimited number of readable replicas, but data can be behind on those.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts but I'm having SQL server standard and I assume Always On is not available for std. By the way with DBM if the secondary DB (mirror) is modified, will the changes reflect in the primary one?

Comment: I guess that's why I need a witness server.

Comment: There is no way to reflect your changes in the primary. Even more - mirror is always in recovery state meaning normal reading methods are not available. This is why you need snapshots if you want to read the DB. However, snapshot is technically a different DB. DBM is an high availability technology, not a load balancing. In case you need a LB I would recommend taking a look on other options, like replication, sync, or log shipping.

Comment: Witness is needed for failover. When mirror server cannot see principal it need another indicator if principal is still available or not. This is done by witness.

Comment: I managed to setup Principle in VM1 and Mirror & Witness in VM2 within the same cloud & same virtual network. Also I noticed that when the Principle is not available Witness automatically sets the Mirror to Principle and no longer in recovery state. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

In order for two Azure VM's to talk they need to be set up in the same affinity group.

A virtual network is a specialized affinity group, where you are able to control the IPs.

Once the virtual network is set up, you should have no problem setting up replication for your database.

Comment: Do they need to resides within the same cloud service as well?

Comment: No, in fact, i dont think they can have the same cloud service.  I've not tried this, but individual cloud services always work better.  I've run into conflicts in the past.

Comment: I thought load balancing will not work with different cloud services. Source: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walterm/archive/2013/06/13/creating-load-balanced-virtual-machines-in-a-virtual-network.aspx

Comment: Could you please confirm above? i.e. load balancing still works with different cloud services within the same Virtual Network? My reading says it doesn't.

Comment: Looks like @Evgeny has experience w/ the cloud service and replication.  I'd go with his advice on that part.

Comment: I'm gonna try this and let you know the progress. Fingers crossed!!